# Can I re-run an ng-directive in AngularJS, or have some "lazy run" for ng directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I get this error

> "Argument 'StatusBarController' is not a function, got undefined" from
>   Angularjs.

The weird thing is that the problem comes from HEADER (StatusBar) page-block, and in a different block I can't see just this piece below here.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in currentPageData.getCustCard.persons">
       <p class="col-xs-9 a24sm-15 listChildrenCard">
           {{person.firstName}}'s {{ person.card.description == "xxxx Default" 
              ? "original" : "custom" }} xxxx card
      </p>
      <div class="col-xs-1 a24sm-3 border"></div>
       <p class="col-xs-3 a24sm-6 costs">&pound;{{ person.card.price }}</p>
</div>
```

This issue happens randomly so because I'm not using angular routing but some engine written by EJS.js, I wrote something that force Angular to active the view `(mainCtrrl.scope().activateView(htmlCtrlContainer))` forcing Angular running controllers through EJS-routing engine.
Now I was wondering whether re-run the ng-repeat directive present on that piece of code.

The Angular part (inside the routing function) where I inlcude any js file if a block requires:

```
for(var i=0; i< blockRegister[block].javascriptURL.length; i++){

                        JsAttached = attachJavaScriptFileInitial(blockRegister[block].javascriptURL[i]);

                        /*****************************  SHOW MAIN VIEW CONTAINER  *************************/

                        JsAttached.done(function(){
                            /*****************************  ANGULAR CONTROLLER LAZY LOAD :: START *************************/
                        if( blockRegister[block].hasOwnProperty("controller") ) {

                            hash[0] = location.hash.split("_")[0].substr(1);

                            var angularMainCtrl = angular.element(document.getElementById("view-container"));
                            var angularHtmlCtrlContainer = angular.element(document.getElementById(section));
                            //console.log( angularMainCtrl.scope(), angularHtmlCtrlContainer );
                            if(!!angularMainCtrl.scope()){ angularMainCtrl.scope().activateView(angularHtmlCtrlContainer); }
                        }
                        /*****************************  ANGULAR CONTROLLER LAZY LOAD :: END *************************/
                    });

                }
```

Comment: The part about EJS routing engine is confusing. Please show more code context

Comment: @charlietfl it's done